# how to map alt+; shortcut to pycharm keymap

Tags: pycharm, keymapping

I'm unable to add the alt+; shortcut to my custom keymap in pycharm, 
Typing the combination on the shortcut mapping window doesn't do anything.
how can i add this shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Mac OS X, a number of shortcuts with the Alt key (including Alt-;) are used by the operating system for typing special characters and cannot normally be handled by other applications. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-17392 for some possible ways to disable the OS handling of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using?
On Ubuntu it may be an [older issue](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1746276).

In my case, PyCharm running in Cinnamon on Ubuntu 14.04 with OpenJDK, the ALT-Key isn't recognized at all.

Comment: If it's still an issue, change the Ubuntu Keyboard Shortcut for the HUD: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117644/how-to-map-alt-shortcut-to-pycharm-keymap/37109432#37109432

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu:

On Unity, the default behavior for the left Alt key is to show the HUD. Therefore it seems that the key event isn't forwarded to PyCharm. If you change the *Key to show the HUD* in the settings (`System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Launchers`), you can use the Alt key in the PyCharm keymap.